# Are there any physical or biological principles that could be applied to electrically ground the human body?

Tags: biology, biochemistry, electricity, safety, body-modification

Exactly what it says on the tin: are there any physical or biological principles that could be applied to [electrically ground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_(electricity)) the human body?

This could take the form of genetic alteration, surgery, etc. - but the end goal is to divert shocks away from vital organs (especially the heart) and preferably towards the ground the person is standing on, and to do so in a fashion that is consistent with known biology and physics.

Assume an attempt at resisting a taser with a voltage of 50,000 volts and an amperage of 3.6 mA.

Comment: I think you want to ground the body and not the nervous system. Otherwise you can compare it with a building. If I ground every electric appliance it's not at all good from the get go. When lightning hits, it can go through everything, killing every single appliance. When I put lightning rod on the building and ground those instead, you'll divert any harmful electricity.

Comment: @Trioxidane Then I'll change it to the body.

Comment: Can you be specific about the exact nature of the electrical event? High voltage follows the surface of the skin and burns. Low voltage follows the fluid pathways and doesn't burn. Low amperage doesn't threaten vital organs, high amperage does. Connecting to the legs rarely threatens the life of the person. Connecting to the chest often does. Electrostatic wrist bands exist to discharge the human body. But they wouldn't discharge house current. So, can you be a LOT more specific about the kind of event we're protecting against?

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact Taser. 50,000 volts; 3.6mA.

Comment: :-) Don't tell me... [edit] your post and add it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## A subdermis faraday cage

Trougth subdermical implant that goes for the enterity of the skin of some very conducting grid of wire, would be anough to make a faraday cage that would shield against electric charges. Then you just need some terminal/contact to ground in the foots.

---

##### Faraday Cage protecting from electric shoot.

[image: Faraday Cage protecting from electric shoot.]
*[source](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/829225350114013331/)*

---

*This feels very devilish*

Comment: How do you divert the charge away once the cage catches it?

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE with the terminal/contact in the foots.

Comment: I'll point out that the workers who perform maintenance on power lines wear full-body metal suits to protect them against electricity.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Looking it up, it appears that those suits are actively cooled by fans pumping air through vents.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Thinking about cooking humans is a canibalism actitude.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi It doesn't need to resist high voltages forever; just long enough for the person to realize that their skin is getting burned and that they should pull away. I'm not stupid enough to think that someone could, say, take a nap on a live power line and survive, even if they were 100% grounded.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE speaking of which skin, at least for mammals, is essential for living (frogs even more so). Better take care how much skin you burn.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises verbatim: "cooking time for **the inside** of that metal suit" - did I say anything about a human? I'm not to be hold responsible for what others think.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Entschuldigung

Comment: @ErdelvonMises Accepted

Comment: The subdermal cage would need to be incredibly low resistance, or it would heat up during the process of discharge (thin wires are also called "fuses.") I like the idea and upvoted it because I can suspend my disbelief about it - but a high enough power (volts * amps = power) would burn the skin above the cage to a crisp and kill the body - but that would be a good "weakness" for story purposes. Everything needs an achilles' heel.