# How would one go about making a subdermal Faraday cage?

Tags: biology, anatomy, electricity, electromagnetism, body-modification

Exactly what it says on the tin: how would one go about making a subdermal (i.e. under the skin) [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage)?

Specifically, are there any physical or biological principles that could be applied to do such a thing, while doing so in a fashion that is consistent with known biology and physics?

Preferably, this could be something that an infant could be genetically modified with and that they could "grow into", but I'm willing to take all comers.

Inspiration [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/216544/87100).

Comment: @ErdelvonMises I'm not doing that until this has been up for a few days, in case a better one comes along. I'm not saying yours is bad, but there might be one that somehow answers my question more accurately.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises, don't be pushy. Answers are not to be accepted based on who most asks for it

Comment: @L.Dutch It just feels weird that the OP aks a question about your answer, but does no accept your answer.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises OP can wait as long as they want before accepting an answer, until they are satisfied with something that solves their problem

Comment: @ErdelvonMises Just because your answer is the best one so far doesn't mean that I need to accept it. For all you know, I could think that it's so far out of left field as to be impossible, and I'm just stress-testing the concept in a different question.

Comment: @L.Dutch I am no trying to force anyone to do anything.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE I never said that you should accept it.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises I mean, you asked me to, so you're kind of splitting hairs here. I'm not interested in continuing this train of discussion.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE Ask does no mean force.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises Dude you've been on the StackExchange network for less than two weeks at this point - cool your jets man or you're just going to get shot down.

Comment: @Eight-BitGuru What did you think I am being bad behaved?

Comment: @ErdelvonMises Yes.

Comment: Just one point to remember: There is not "one" faraday cage. The mesh size defines the wave lengths that get through. You have to go solid (i.e. no mesh at all) to catch pretty much everything. And with visible light being just another wave length, you might not want to do so.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Frame shift: subepithelial (superdermal) Faraday cage

This is an answer to a slightly different question:  Putting the conductive layer under the dermis is hard, because the bottom edge of the dermis is irregular and intertwined with the hypodermis.  It could be placed more deeply (superficial fascia, etc), but I'd rather look to the boundary of the two major layers of the skin: the **basement membrane**.  Putting the cage *above* the dermal layer means that it defeats miniature spying devices with which the victim might have been tattooed via weapons shot at protests (I've seen a paper proposing these about 20 years ago, ought to look for it...) or injected/vaccinated etc., which could hide in the dermis itself.

The basement membrane provides a fairly continuous barrier around the body.  We just need to make it electric.  For this I'll suggest [beta-carotene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%92-Carotene) as raw material.  This is pretty much what biology uses for wire - in plants, it collects light for photosynthesis, and in humans, related compounds (vitamin A and more specifically 11-cis-retinal) are used to detect light.  If we eat it in large excess, the skin will take on an orange color.  We're going to change that color so it absorbs a wider range of (lower) frequencies.

[image: beta carotene with 11 conjugated double bonds]

The trick of this molecule is in the double bonds (=) which can be shifted to either side and still connect all the atoms correctly, *if* charge is introduced to one end and the other end.  All we need to do to make it more graphite-like (conductive) is to *extend* this network by an enzymatic reaction that links these structures together with another bond.  We need to evolve a new enzyme from scratch, most likely, which is a task of some difficulty but definitely doable, especially since there are many known domains that bind to and react with vitamin A derivatives.  I only took the briefest look at PubMed to scan for something already in existence, and there's a chance if you dig into KEGG or other compilations of biochemical pathways you can find something useful already from nature.

When making such an enzyme, we should tweak it during development so that:

- It has a relatively poor binding affinity to beta-carotene.  We don't want it stealing retinoic acid needed during development or vitamin A the baby needs for night vision - only when beta-carotene is consumed *in excess* will an appreciable amount bind and react.
- The reaction has some reversibility.  We're not going to spend a fortune in energy to make this happen, and we don't mind if the network can spontaneously be broken down when beta-carotene concentrations are low.  This will cause the network to double as a vitamin storage for the infant and ensure it is *possible* to give up the cage with a prolonged period of sticking to the Recommended Daily Allowance, if there is a medical imaging issue.  But vitamins with megadoses of beta carotene have been very easily available; and if that fails, there are carrots (yikes!), so this is not a large bother.
- The enzymes for the reaction need to include binding sites that attach somewhere on proteins of the basement membrane, for obvious reasons.  Otherwise we're laying these down in random places.  They should be secreted by basal epithelial cells, I suppose.  Their production should be very strongly repressed in any tissue of the eye, and their activity should be allosterically inhibited by ceramide or other compounds common in the retina.  More safety considerations would be needed ... we don't want any foul ups!

*[Apology for a minor jest:  the proper term is **supra**dermal, but "Superdermis" sounded more heroic]*

Comment: Thank you for a scientific answer and a relevant frame shift. +1

Answer (score 4):

Tattoos made with conductive ink have been proposed. All the examples I've seen so far have been surface ink. I'm not sure if that's for reasons of toxicity or because people don't seriously want to have permanent circuitboards inscribed in the skin. But the surface ones are conductive enough to attach lights and power sources.

See [Silver Nanowire Inks for Direct-Write Electronic Tattoo Applications](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6689233/)

Comment: ...did you make an account just to answer this question?

Comment: No, I didn't make an account at all. I have philosophical/moral objections to any form of Argument from Authority, so I don't like to participate in any system using 'reputation' scores. But I do enjoy answering questions, and being helpful.

Comment: I think that random Internet strangers are as far from authority as one can get, but you do you.

Comment: We would be wiser by far to consider all 'authorities' and 'experts' like they were random internet strangers, and judge each answer on its own merits. I try not to make a big deal of it. Each to their own.

Comment: @NulliusinVerba I wholeheartedly disagree. Expert opinion should absolutely be valued above those from "random internet strangers", and equating them in importance only leads to situations like: "Here on my left we have Dr. So-and-so who has three Ph.D.s in related fields and holds the Nobel Prize in one of those fields, and on my right we have Mrs. Karen Smith who watched a YouTube video once. Let's have them debate each other on live television and let the audience decide who is right." This isn't to say that experts are always right by default, but their opinion is by far more valuable.

Comment: @Abion47 Argument screens off authority. If, on further questioning, the Nobel Prize-winning PhD says that [liquid water can form nanostructures when exposed to pathogenic DNA, _because the DNA emits radio waves_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobel_disease#Luc_Montagnier), you can probably ignore the conclusion.

Comment: If a point is unjustified, you should believe an expert more than a non-expert. However, Stack Exchange answers are expected to be complete, rather than just “I told you so”, so the validity of a _good_ answer is completely independent of the reputation of its author.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Absolutely true, if the expert is saying something completely off the wall, then it invalidates his position of authority. What I'm saying is that, all else being equal, experts should absolutely have more credibility than random passersby from a starting position. Credibility is like trust - it must be earned and it can be lost.

Comment: I also agree on the StackExchange topic. The point system on SE sites isn't like social media popularity contests or circlejerks. Answers live or die based on their quality, informativeness, and their completeness. If someone has a lot of points, that means they have a track record of providing answers that meet those criteria, and thus their "authority" is earned. But that also doesn't mean they will get it right 100% of the time - I've seen no shortage of questions where a first-time poster beat a grizzled SE veteran in votes.

Comment: @Abion47 Consider the extreme case: mathematicians. If a mathematician claims something, you might choose to believe them (or not) based on their reputation. If a mathematician hands you a proof, it doesn't matter if they're widely considered a crank; if the maths checks out, the maths checks out. All else being equal, if somebody has provided you with their _entire reason for believing something_, you can ignore their authority.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 The layperson wouldn't benefit from a mathematician handing them a proof, as depending on its complexity they would likely be unable to read it much less verify it. This is why the appeal to authority, while fallacious, is oftentimes unavoidable when dealing with the general public because, at the end of the day, people have neither the time nor the level of understanding to properly vet an expert's claim. But in the long run, we already have a system for this - peer review. Expert claims can be debunked by other experts, and if enough of them speak up, the debunking will stick.

Answer (score 2):

It would be difficult to get a biological process that'd create a metalic mesh, becuase the thing DNA is good at making, protein, and similar biology-ish chemicals is the thing metal isn't.

However, all is not lost! It doesn't necessarily have to be metal! There are conductive proteins, and it might be feasible that a correctly designed mesh would have similar properties to a faraday cage.

Heres at least one suggestion;-
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27409066/

I'm not too sure the physics of this, and I'm not sure an internal faraday cage is going to be particularly useful, since the goal is to keep that EM energy *away* from the body, rather than ground it *inside* of the body. That might require a physicist to chime in on this. I might add, that grounding is important, the EM captured and diverted by the cage has to go somewhere. Newton does not negotiate with terrorists and sci-fi authors, conservation laws are a constant in any concievable universe worth concocting.. So you'd have to work that problem out too.

If you put it on the surface though, you could have your character displaying a nice metalic sheen, since one property of conductivity is reflectivity.

Comment: Is this sufficient?  From the image on the [wiley page](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/smll.201601112) they have a conductivity of 977 S/cm, compared to copper of 58.14 x 10^6 S/m.

Comment: @Dave satisfactory. Microwave won't penetrate more than 1-2cm into your body. It may boil your skin, but rest assured your heart will continue beating in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Blood vessels are a wonderful criss-crossing madness on their own. I'm not entirely certain how feasible or survivable this is, but since there is iron in our blood and copper in the blood of molluscs I'd imagine it wouldn't be too big of a stretch, even if nothing in nature currently has this, for the body to use iron/copper atoms in the construction of a person's veins at a relatively high amount/concentration.

This may lead to something like the veins themselves being slightly metallic with all the good and the bad that comes from that. Who/whatever has these veins would be rather conductive throughout their whole body and will have a bit of a bad time at airports and all sorts of situations that involve metal detectors.

Comment: There is iron in our blood in the same sense that there is chlorine in table salt. You can rub salt into wounds, and even eat it, but a tiny bit of chlorine gas and your skin will start burning. I'm not saying iron is _not_ survivable, but further research is needed; I think you'd have to have a maintenance process to stop the metal being reacted away, at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

**Bad news**: to protect against high voltages, you need a *very low resistance*, probably only to be found in **metals**.

So unless you go the way of some semi-plausible body-temperature organic superconductor, *which you could*, the only alternative is a metallic mesh, probably gold, or copper or silver sheathed with something biocompatible and non reactive.

The advantage with gold is that beside having very low resistance, you can have *really* tiny wires, that do not interfere with the organism and need little sheathing.

To thread the wires throughout the skin, you'll need either specialized mites (genetically engineered Demodex for example, except they'd need to burrow - so, something more like [D. Medinensis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracunculus_medinensis)) or nanomachines, and a gold-based skin lotion to supply them with the raw materials. The lotion could contain millions of really tiny carabiners, and the mites would assemble them in chains and thread them throughout the organism.

Or the mites could assemble the carabiners themselves out of ordinary materials, building exotic compounds such as bond-strained thiafulvalene-catenane ([fulvalene](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/jpa-00231730/document) was one of the first groups used in high temperature superconduction back in the '80s, and catenanes are a novel class of pseudopolymers that possess *literally* infinite flexibility. Best of all, they could be built from ordinary organic CHNOPS if one had the appropriate molecular machinery. The only hand-waving here is the hypothesis that bond-straining certain groups could "gift" them with superconductivity, as it seems to happen with [thiocarbo-pseudohydride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonaceous_sulfur_hydride)).

Answer (score 0):

If your idea is protect the whole body from microwaves you are out of luck. No way to metallize a human body skin is scientifically plausible. But human body skin and muscles are rich in salt and salt is conductive. Maybe if you connect such tissues to earth you cold make a reasonable Faraday Cage. But attention!!! It can work to block low energy electromagnetic waves. It will not protect from strong microwave action. As Adrian Colomitchi has commented it is not a good idea, and, connect skin and muscles to earth cam make you much more in risk of ordinary electric shock.

But if your idea is people were born with a natural "Tin foil hat" you could be more lucky.

You need to metallize only the skull. I think, maybe, because human skull is mostly made of mineral (calcium) matter some none could mess up with DNA to make the human skull bone metallized with iron, maybe cooper.